# Designing a cache initializer

Tags: java, caching, design-patterns, hazelcast

I need to write a caching solution for my web application.

Basically I have lists of different objects that are kept in memory using [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/). Each time the application starts the objects are loaded into memory from a persistent store. From time to time, the objects are persisted again back into the store.

The application is real-time (lots of websockets receive client requests modifying the data) so I need to be able to obtain/retrieve those objects very fast based on different type of ids and/or simple search criterias.

I was thinking to have different maps where the key represents the id and the value is the the instance of the object.

For example a certain type of object I will have a number maps (or multimaps):

1. map1: < some_internal_key, object >
2. map2: < some_other_internal_key, object >
3. map3: < some_other_internal_key2, object >
4. map4: < a_search_criteria, list< objects_meeting_the_criteria > >
5. map5: < another_search_criteria, list < objects_meeting_the_criteria > >

....

And so on.

Those objects should be synchronized across all the 10 Maps, meaning if one object is modified, those modifications should be be available into all the maps. Sometimes, because this modifications the search criterias can be affected, so some objects should be associated with other keys.

From a code perspective how would you design this mechanism ?

Do you have a better idea ?

The problem keeping all the objects synchronized will be resolved if I keep in the map the same references. But from a caching perspective how to I track changes in order to recalculate the new objects <-> criteria associations ?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use predicate to retrieve the object from map? Also, if you need a big throughput maybe you should consider using entryprocessors if your plan is to modify the items?

Answer (score 1):

Only store the object once and then use the key to reference the stored object.

So for your example:

```
map1: < some_internal_key, object >
```

And then:

```
map2: < some_other_internal_key, some_internal_key >
```

You can probably keep map2 in memory, because it has no consistency issues. So the additional lookup is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

As @travikk mentioned, Hazelcast supports not only lookups by key but lookups by different properties of an object - [Distributed Query / Predicate API](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query). Hazelcast also supports [indexes](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#indexing-queries) for faster search. If you need to populate another map/cache based on defined criteria, you can use [Continuous Query Cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query).
Of course, you can store objects in the different map, but if you need to co-locate related data you take a look on [Data Affinity](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#data-affinity) techniques.
If you need to modify a content of several distributed objects (maps, lists, sets, etc) transactionally, you can use [Transactional Context](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#transactions).

As you can see, there are many features available at your disposal in Hazelcast so you don't need to invent a the wheel and manually manage contents of your maps.

Cheers,
Vik